# steam problem ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, steam

term keeps popping up when I run it, then two pop-ups.

[image: error message pop-up 1]

[image: error message pop-up 2]

After I the term false to install the files here is what the term says:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for matti:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Comment: Let's try the installation manually. What's the output of `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it my Self I uninstilled it. And instead of downloading from steam. Or the ubuntu store I used the terminal.